# How to set divs value from an array using jquery.each()

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to iterate through some divs changing their text using `$.each()`.
The text is in an array, and what i'd like to do is to change it for each divs contained into a parent.

In the code that i have now, it prints only the last array entry.

This is the code:

```
parent=$(".parent");
array = ['one','two','three','four','five','six'];

$.each( array, function( i, val ) {
  $( ".parent div" ).text(val);
});
```

Here's an example that should explain my issue better:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbGXeL?editors=101

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbGXzv?editors=101

```
$.each( array, function( i, val ) {
  $( ".parent div" ).eq(i).text(val);
});
```

You can use [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select the element using the index. Assumes array length matches div count.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
parent = $(".parent");
array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];

$.each(array, function (i, val) {
    console.log(i, val)
    $(".parent div:eq(" + i + ")").text(val);
});
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVaGeN?editors=101

About eq: When you use a jquery selector, it returns an array of elements which matches the css selector. SO, in order to access a specific element inside an array, you need to use the index. And eq or get does that.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) method accepts a function as parameter, use it:

```
$( ".parent div" ).text(function(i){
  return array[i];
});
```

Comment: that could work as well, but text is just for this example. In my projecy i need to add a data-attribute

Comment: @Nick So provide relevant example, `attr()` method accepts a function too (but not `data()` method, which anyway doesn't set attribute but...)  See updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPJWYe?editors=101

Comment: @Nick So doesn't it answers your question? I ask it regarding downvote

Answer (score 0):

The selector you've used, i.e. `$(".parent div")` applies to any `div` that is a child of the `.parent` `div`.

This means on each iteration, the `.each()` method first looks for the filter you've specified (i.e. ANY child div) and inserts the text into the div (in this case all divs). In the end, you are left with the last value of `array` being inserted to ALL of the divs.

Try the approaches specified in other answers or as such:

```
parent=$(".parent");
array = ['one','two','three','four','five','six'];

$.each( parent.children('div'), function( i, div ) {
  $( div ).text(array[i]);
});
```

[Working Sample Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPJWYe?editors=101)